# EWS subscribe to streaming notifications in the inbox

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I trying to write a Console Application which will establish a connection to a mailbox using EWS and then print a line every time a new email is received.

The end result once I have this working is to turn this into a service, and have a task created every time an email arrives in a certain mailbox, but for now I cant get the Console to write a line upon receipt.

**Console Application Project**

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
         WebCredentials wbcred = new WebCredentials("myusername", "mypassw0rd");
         service.Credentials = wbcred;
         service.AutodiscoverUrl("myemailaddress@mydomain.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

         EWSConnection.SetStreamingNotifications(service);
    }

    internal static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
    {
        //The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL
        bool result = false;

        Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);
        if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
        {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    } 
}
```

**Class Library Project**

**EWSConnection.cs**

```
  public static void SetStreamingNotifications(ExchangeService service)
        {
            StreamingSubscription subscription;

            // Subscribe to streaming notifications in the Inbox. 
            subscription = service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(
                new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox },
                EventType.NewMail);

            // Create a streaming connection to the service object, over which events are returned to the client.
            // Keep the streaming connection open for 30 minutes.
            StreamingSubscriptionConnection connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(service, 30);
            connection.AddSubscription(subscription);
            connection.OnNotificationEvent += OnEvent;
            connection.OnDisconnect += OnDisconnect;
            connection.Open();

            bool status = connection.IsOpen;
            Console.WriteLine($"Connection Open:{status}");
        }
```

I can add the `OnEvent` and `OnDisconnect` methods if required. What's happening is the console prints

> Connection Open:True Press any key to continue . . .

Then, when I send an email to that mailbox nothing happens, no break points are triggered and nothing is output to the console, which is what those two methods do.

Why is my `OnEvent` method not firing?

**Edit - OnEvent & OnDisconnect methods**

```
 public static void OnEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
        {
            StreamingSubscription subscription = args.Subscription;

            // Loop through all item-related events. 
            foreach (NotificationEvent notification in args.Events)
            {

                switch (notification.EventType)
                {
                    case EventType.NewMail:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n————-Mail created:————-");
                        break;
                    case EventType.Created:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n————-Item or folder created:————-");
                        break;
                    case EventType.Deleted:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n————-Item or folder deleted:————-");
                        break;
                }
                // Display the notification identifier. 
                if (notification is ItemEvent)
                {
                    // The NotificationEvent for an e-mail message is an ItemEvent. 
                    ItemEvent itemEvent = (ItemEvent)notification;
                    Console.WriteLine("\nItemId: " + itemEvent.ItemId.UniqueId);
                }
                else
                {
                    // The NotificationEvent for a folder is an FolderEvent. 
                    FolderEvent folderEvent = (FolderEvent)notification;
                    Console.WriteLine("\nFolderId: " + folderEvent.FolderId.UniqueId);
                }
            }
        }
```

and

```
public static void OnDisconnect(object sender, SubscriptionErrorEventArgs args)
{
    // Cast the sender as a StreamingSubscriptionConnection object.           
    StreamingSubscriptionConnection connection = (StreamingSubscriptionConnection)sender;
    // Ask the user if they want to reconnect or close the subscription. 
    ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
    Console.WriteLine("The connection to the subscription is disconnected.");
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to reconnect to the subscription? Y/N");
    while (true)
    {
        cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
        {
            if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
            {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection open.");
                break;
            }
            else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.N)
            {
                // The ReadKey in the Main() consumes the E. 
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress E to exit");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A few questions: Is your OnEvent delegate signature correct? Can you provide your code for the delegate please? Does OnDisconnect fire?

Comment: Nothing fires, if I set a debug in either event when I start it up it immediately finishes running

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annoyingly, I was missing the Console.ReadKey() method. It worked as expected once I added this...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
        WebCredentials wbcred = new WebCredentials("myusername", "mypassw0rd","myDomain");
        service.Credentials = wbcred;
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("myemailaddress@mydomain.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

        EWSConnection.SetStreamingNotifications(service);

        Console.ReadKey(); //<-- this was missing
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind the methods to the current subscription as this

```
connection.OnNotificationEvent +=
                new StreamingSubscriptionConnection.NotificationEventDelegate(OnEvent);
connection.OnDisconnect +=
        new StreamingSubscriptionConnection.SubscriptionErrorDelegate(OnDisconnect);
```

Here's a [example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2010/12/22/working-with-streaming-notifications-by-using-the-ews-managed-api/)

Comment: This is how I had it initially however the StreamingSubscriptionConnection.NotifcationEventDelegate line is greyed and it says "Redundant Explicit Delegate Creation"

Comment: @JsonStatham Do you get compile error or is this Refactor that tells you?

Comment: No complication error, just intellisense suggests its redundant code. With or without it the even does not fire.

Comment: @JsonStatham hmm..I can't spot anything else  except that is out of order.

Comment: im assuming when it says "press any key to continue" the service is still running so if I email my mailbox it should still be picked up?

Comment: @JsonStatham Did you get this after the "Connection Open.." line which the SetStreamingNotifications() writes? Then the answer is yes. The streaming is up and running as long as the console is on until the connection closes after 30 minutes

Comment: Yes it says this after Connection Open: True

Comment: @JsonStatham I really think you should apply my suggested changes and rebuild the solution, then start the console and after the console writes that the connection is open: True, send a email to the mail. It should work.

Comment: The example you have provided is the example I have used. I have applied your suggested changes and rebuilt the solution. The OnEvent never fires.

Comment: @JsonStatham ok, Then there's not much I can help with. GL. BTW: You got the best SO name hehe It's amaizing

Comment: So, did you find a way how to do it? Is it what you added like an answer? Cause, I have the same problem that I need to get a notification when I will get a message in my inbox.